# Using Angular's UI-Router to create a dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building a blog in Angular and using ui-router to handle my states.  When I resolve the article using the `resolve` object, I want to be able to dynamically change the `<title>` tag.  This is done by populating the `data` object with an element called `pageTitle`.

How do I pass in dynamic data from the `resolve` key into the `data` key?

Plunkr at http://plnkr.co/edit/N8bhMHfKtUmxVhytnsCA?p=info

I have managed this before so I know it's possible, but I don't have access to that project any more.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the reason that the data is being presented as-is is because I need to interpolate the data.  This will then compile {{ article.getContent() }} as the relevant content.

To help with interpolating  tags, I wrote a library to do it for me automatically https://github.com/riggerthegeek/ng-page-title

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want resolved keys in your data? You can also get the resolved keys in the controller

```
resolve: {
  article: function () {
    /* Go to DB and get article */
    return {
      getTitle: function () {
        return "Article 1";
      },
      getContent: function () {
        return "Hello, this is my content";
      }
    };
  }
},
controller: "ctrl"
```

And in the controller you can inject article

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, article){...});
```

Comment: Yes I do.  I have a directive that controls what appears in the <title> tag.  Makes my code lovely and DRY.  If you look at the Plunkr, there's already a controller in there too.